# How to fix Samsung Galaxy Note 3 Loose Home Button?

Tags: samsung

Samsung's Note 3 smartphone has cool features and utilities than other smartphone in market. And even it doesn't heat in long use. But Home button stuck randomly while using and sometimes Volume button also has same problem. read brief in http://eviltek.blogspot.com/2013/12/how-to-fix-samsung-galaxy-note-3-loose.html

How to Fix it

Answer (score 1):

If your device is still in warranty I'd stop fiddling with it and get it fixed at an authorized service center. Opening the device yourself will void warranty.

Answer (score -1):

It is a broken phone. send it back to Samsung. I also use the features that it comes with and mine works fine.

Comment: Why would you send a Samsung phone to Google?

Comment: I'm sorry I ment Samsung editing now